# Facebook Comments plugin: Moderate past comments (blacklisted words)

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I've been running Facebook's Comments plugin for a while and I've got a profanity abuse problem at one of my sites.

I've recently placed the code necessary for moderation, Facebook's debugger says all it's fine and my moderation console works so I included a blacklist with the idea of using it as profanity filter.

The thing is, it seems to work, but **past comments aren't filtered**.
It seems this is a limitation of the tool (thanks John Hall).

Is there a way to moderate past comments?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior sounds correct and appears to the same for comment boxes I've moderated. I just checked the [Facebook Comments FAQ - How does the blacklisting words work?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) and it pretty much says the same thing:

> The content of new comments is checked against the blacklist of terms to see if this comment should have limited visibility.

Which confirms that the filtering is applied only to **new comments**.

Comment: Thanks, I did a slight change to the question.

Comment: I don't think can moderate past comments but you an potentially delete all comments and start afresh. One way is to add a hashtag at the end of the page url (#something), which makes it unique, that should clear all the comments.